# Override Default Action of QRCode

Tags: c#, qr-code

I have several hundred items at my facility that are labeled with QR Codes. These QR codes, when read, try to open up a vendor’s web app. I want to write my own program but still use the same QR Code. Is this possible or will I need to generate my own QR code specific to my program?

Comment: QR codes are just data. It's the reader application that interprets that data and acts on it. Decode the raw data and see what it contains. Is it a URL? Write a reader that parses the URL and uses whatever identifier it contains to do what *you* want with it.

Comment: If you could show us an example of the data within the QR code

Comment: Currently, this is just an idea. I scanned the QR code with my iPhone and it wanted to open up a web browser. I'll download a QR Reader app and see what it tries to do.

Comment: I have posted a C# project [here](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t18064-) that uses the LEADTOOLS SDK to extract data from QR code and perform simple checking to see if the data is a URI and optionally open it in a browser. (Disclosure: I work for the SDK’s vendor). You can modify the project to parse the URI instead of opening it, and extract whatever information you need from it. If  you would like to try this project, the SDK has a [free evaluation here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads)